# Is there a way to disable the hotkeys?

Tags: feature-request, edits, keyboard-shortcuts

I navigate with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>,<kbd>p</kbd>,<kbd>f</kbd>,<kbd>b</kbd> (readline/[Emacs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs) keys), so that I don't have to move my hands too much and get [RSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repetitive_strain_injury) again. Is there a way to disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> being hotkey for **bold**?

Note that this is not just an Emacs thing. Standard web browsers, like Firefox and Chrome, use things like
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to navigate to the Google search bar and address bar respectively.

Comment: Agree. overriding ctrl bindings should never be done haphazardly.

Comment: +1 please add a preference to turn it off, or change the keys to something that doesn't interfere, or just remove the feature altogether. I run into this problem several times a day, and it's starting to piss me off.

Comment: In Firefox I often usek Ctrl-k to navigate to the Google search bar.  In Chrome I often use Ctrl-l to navigate to the address bar.  I hate that I cannot use these while asking or answering a question.

Comment: Historically, preferences are frowned upon.  Also, many more people want the key bindings than don't want them, so it's likely that you'll have to come up with a user-side solution such as a userscript in order to overcome this issue.

Comment: @AdamDavis "many more people want the key bindings than don't want them" Do you have any evidence to back up that claim?

Comment: @MichaelMcGowan Nope.  Other than it was included by default in the WMD editor, we've had it for years, and questions suggesting changing or removing them never get more than a handful of votes.  If it were not widely valued, or if it regularly got in the way of people's usage of the site, it would get a lot more scrutiny every time this came up.  This request is nearly 3 years old and only has 18 supporters, out of millions of Stack Overflow users, who would surely complain if it was an annoying problem.

Comment: @MichaelMcGowan - control-b to make text bold is I think a much, much more common operation than whatever crazy emacs voodoo OP is talking about.  Control-b for bold works in MS Word, Gmail, Google Docs, etc.  Adam Davis is most likely right in his assertion, but I doubt anyone has stats to back it up.

Comment: @AdamRackis Neither Gmail nor Google Docs (Chrome/OS X) does anything special with Ctrl-B for me. Contrariwise, does any editor without this feature have people requesting it? Wikipedia doesn't work like this, nor does Blogger, Facebook, Twitter...

Comment: The CTRL + H is also annoying, since muscle memory expects character deletion (instead you get the `Heading` shortcut).

Comment: I should add to this. The 'escape' key is mapped to 'browser back'. I pressed it to cancel a search-in-page operation. Annoying.

Comment: `Ctrl-B` for moving the cursor back is not "Emacs Voodoo" as suggested above, it's a standard keyboard command in macOS that works **everywhere**. Well, except for SO.

Comment: Agreed, Emacs keys works absolutely everywhere in Unix except browsers.

Comment: It does work even in browsers. It works in the address field and in every text input field on every website I use in Safari, Chrome and Firefox. Stack Overflow (and the other Stack Exchanges) is literally the only place for me where `Ctrl-B` does not work.

Comment: Ctrl-B specifically maybe (though for me at least it's working in fewer and fewer places, for example not in the address bar), but I was referring to Emacs keys in general. E.g. Ctrl-N and many others.

Comment: I use `Ctrl-N`, `Ctrl-P`, `Ctrl-B`, `Ctrl-F`, `Ctrl-A`, and `Ctrl-K` in macOS in all kinds of applications and on all kinds of websites in different browsers. For me these commands just work everywhere out of the box. Only on Stack Overflow `Ctrl-B` and `Ctrl-K` do not work because they remapped them without an option to disable that.

Comment: @AdamRackis on macOS you're confusing Ctrl-B with Cmd-B

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### No.

The correct answer to the above yes/no question is "no".

I do appreciate the other answers suggested here. They offer creative workarounds, and I appreciate the thought people put into coming up with them.

But hacking your browser via "user scripts" or "bookmarklets" isn't really what's being asked for here. Even most developers -- let alone ordinary Stack Exchange users -- are not aware of such options, much less how to install and use them (and evaluate their security risk, etc.). Furthermore, such solutions will likely be brittle (not future-proof).

Think about it this way: If a user had asked *"How do I change this shortcut?"* and one of the responses was *"Here's a Linux kernel patch I wrote for you,"* would you accept that as an answer? I'd upvote it (*thanks for the effort!*), but I wouldn't accept it.

A proper solution to the OP's problem would be a built-in SE preference to disable these frustrating hotkey settings permanently. Until that solution exists, the answer to this question is "no".

Comment: I believe the underlying problem is a failure of platform localization.  Apple guidelines [1] guide against changing system keyboard control shortcuts.  Control-B on a Mac should be localized to command-B etc.  I would also note that if this site is not a forum for discussing stackexchange common functionality, then what is?

[1] https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/inputs/keyboards#custom-keyboard-shortcuts

Comment: No, the underlying problem is a website, that has no clue about the user's environment, forcing shortcuts on that environment, breaking the user's workflow and even making itself unusable (e.g. in case of handicapped users who can't leave such website). Any keyboard shortcuts should only be set by the user's browser and never served by the website and if said website was stubborn enough to serve key bindings, it should offer an option to disable them. Period. There's no space for discussion - it's common sense.

Answer (score 31):

### Bookmarklet:

```js
javascript:(function(a,p){function i(e){e.stopPropagation()};p[a]('keydown',i,!0);p[a]('keypress',i,!0);p[a]('keyup',i,!0);})('addEventListener',$('#wmd-input').parent()[0]);
```

### User Script:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Cya WMD shortcuts
// @namespace      Rob W
// @version        1.0
// @match          https://stackoverflow.com/*
// @match          https://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match          https://superuser.com/*
// @match          https://meta.superuser.com/*
// @match          https://serverfault.com/*
// @match          https://meta.serverfault.com/*
// @match          https://askubuntu.com/*
// @match          https://meta.askubuntu.com/*
// @match          https://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match          https://stackapps.com/*
// @run-at         document-end
// @grant          none
// ==/UserScript==

(typeof unsafeWindow !== 'undefined' ? unsafeWindow : window).$(function() {
    var p = document.getElementById('wmd-input');
    if (!p) return;
    p = p.parentNode;
    function ignore(e){e.stopPropagation();}    
    p.addEventListener('keydown', ignore, true);
    p.addEventListener('keypress', ignore, true);
    p.addEventListener('keyup', ignore, true);
});
```

### Technical details

- In the [W3C event model](https://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html#link4), JavaScript events are fired in two ways:
- Capture (The events are fired,  from the top of the document to the target)
- Bubble (The events bubble from the target to the top of the document).
- In [`wmd.js`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/js/wmd.js), the events are bound using `addEventListener`, in the bubbling phase.
- The event is added to the parent node of the element, with the capturing flag. Inside the event listener, [`event.stopPropagation();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.stopPropagation) is called, to stop the event from propagating further.
- As a result, **all WMD shortcuts are disabled**.

### Chrome extension

1. Create a directory, and store the following two files in it.
2. Visit chrome://extensions/
3. Enable Developer mode
4. Click on the button <kbd>Load unpacked extension...</kbd>.
5. Select the directory from step 1.

manifest.json

```json
{
    "name": "Cya WMD shortcuts",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "1.0",
    "content_scripts": [{
        "js": ["contentscript.js"],
        "matches": [
            "https://stackoverflow.com/*",
            "https://*.stackoverflow.com/*",
            "https://superuser.com/*",
            "https://meta.superuser.com/*",
            "https://serverfault.com/*",
            "https://meta.serverfault.com/*",
            "https://askubuntu.com/*",
            "https://meta.askubuntu.com/*",
            "https://*.stackexchange.com/*",
            "https://stackapps.com/*"
        ]
    }]
}
```

contentscript.js

```js
var p = document.getElementById('wmd-input');
if (p) {
    p = p.parentNode;
    var ignore = function(e){e.stopPropagation();};
    p.addEventListener('keydown', ignore, true);
    p.addEventListener('keypress', ignore, true);
    p.addEventListener('keyup', ignore, true);
}
```

Comment: PS. Between the creation of this question and this answer, [this feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120758/wmd-shortcut-conflict-with-unicode-input-mode-ctrl-shift-u) has been approved. `Ctrl+shift+*` and `Ctrl+alt+*` key combinations are not affected, by default.

Comment: @blahdiblah Not tested, but you could insert `if(e.ctrlKey)` before `e.stopPropagation();` so that the script is only activated for `Ctrl` + * key combinations.

Comment: As per your suggestion, changing `i(e)` and `ignore(e)` to `ignore(e){e.metaKey && e.stopPropagation();}` removes the problematic keyboard shortcut behavior, but doesn't trigger a captcha all the time.

Comment: @RobW thanks, this is fantastic! i use cmd+L compulsively to to go the location bar in chrome on a mac, and it drives me batty that SE thinks its a good idea to override default shortcuts. cmd+R works now too, to refresh the page.

Comment: @Jeff I am actually used to Ctrl+L for links. I've got your issue with Chrome's Developer tools: In the console, Ctrl + L is overridden. I've found that Ctrl+K focuses the omnibar with search. Then it's a matter of entering the keywords (if you were really going to search) or hitting backspace and type the full URL to continue.

Comment: great help, in Firefox/Vimperator the webpage Ctrl+I shortcut interferes with Vimperator's edit-in-external-editor shortcut. In some Firefox versions this results in inserting a emphasized text before opening gvim - in current versions gvim is completely blocked. Exorbitantly annoying. As a quickfix opening your booklet code via ESC :o works fine in Vimperator.

Comment: Bookmarklet does not work anymore with current so site/Firefox 27.

Comment: The script mostly does not work in Chrome on MacOS.  The editor textarea id seems to be `wmd-input-52143651` instead of just `wmd-input`, with a specific number for each instance.

Comment: @chqrlie You can use this two line modification `var wmdInputId = document.querySelector('[id^="wmd-input"]').id;` 
`var p = document.getElementById(wmdInputId);` . Added in answer too.

Comment: I packaged your extension for [the chrome store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/no-stackexchange-editor-k/nhdklhaffdlobbdgheaehofbnfebeddm?hl=en-US)

Comment: When you press "Edit" on an answer, that creates the textbox then and there, so you'll need to click your bookmarklet again to disable the keys. [My extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/no-stackexchange-editor-k/nhdklhaffdlobbdgheaehofbnfebeddm?hl=en-US) listens for when new elements are added to the page, so it just works(tm)

Comment: Unfortunately, this script has been implicated in [triggering bot detection by SX](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149396/620615).

Comment: `"manifest_version": 2` is now obsolete. [Boris extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/no-stack-exchange-editor/nhdklhaffdlobbdgheaehofbnfebeddm) has been updated to version 3

Answer (score 17):

I feel for you, as I have a similar problem... if not worse :-(

On contemporary Hungarian keyboards, some special characters are mapped to key combinations involving the <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> (aka <kbd>AltGr</kbd>) key. Such as

- `[` to RightAlt+F,
- `]` to RightAlt+G ...which opens the "Insert Image" dialog on SO,
- `{` to RightAlt+B ...which evokes **strong text** on SO,
- `}` to RightAlt+N.

Do I need to explain how terrible it is to try to write e.g. Java code with this keyboard mapping? Lately I realized that the Search box doesn't have these mappings - so if I need a closing square bracket or an opening curly bracket (and there is no code snippet around in the actual post to copy from), all I need is to switch to the Search box, type the character, select it, Ctrl+X, back to the Editor box, Ctrl+V...

Even though this is not an answer to your question in the strict sense, at least (hopefully) it shows that this problem is not as marginal as it may seem at first sight.

Comment: This is why [you're not supposed to use Ctrl+Alt+whatever as a keyboard shortcut](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/03/29/101121.aspx).

Comment: You're not supposed to use keyboard shortcuts at all. In many systems for handicapped users shortcuts are mapped to a single key (e.g. `d` to delete active tab, `f` to follow links, `i` to start typing). Stealing these shortcuts successfully traps such users and they can't continue their work without someone helping them to close the website.

Comment: @cprn keyboard shortcuts are very useful.

Comment: @BorisVerkhovskiy Yes, when they're set up entirely on the client side by the user so that they wouldn't conflict with their normal workflow, not when they're served by the website that has no clue about the user's environment. The idea of websites using shortcuts is plain stupid. There's no way of telling what functionality the website is taking away from the user, e.g. the most moronic of them all - using `/` to jump to a website's search bar - makes every such website unusable for people using most of the voice controlled browsers because they can't leave it - they have to reboot.

Answer (score 4):

Here is Rob W's script, updated to only block cntrl-* and fixed so that it works with NinjaKit which is a Safari extension for running user scripts. Re-did it for this question on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/60587/possible-to-disable-custom-javascript-keybindings-in-safari)

NinjaKit:
https://github.com/os0x/NinjaKit

Script:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Cya WMD shortcuts
// @namespace      Rob W
// @version        1.0
// @include          https://apple.stackexchange.com/*
// @include          http://stackoverflow.com/*
// @include          http://superuser.com/*
// @include          http://meta.superuser.com/*
// @include          http://serverfault.com/*
// @include          http://meta.serverfault.com/*
// @include          http://askubuntu.com/*
// @include          http://meta.askubuntu.com/*
// @include          http://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @include          http://answers.onstartups.com/*
// @include          http://meta.answers.onstartups.com/*
// @include          http://stackapps.com/*
// @run-at         document-end
// @grant          none
// ==/UserScript==
(function () {
    var p = document.getElementById('wmd-input');
    console.log("wmd-input:" + p);
    if (p) {
        p = p.parentNode;

        function ignore(e) {
            if (e.ctrlKey) {
                e.stopPropagation();
            }
        }
        p.addEventListener('keydown', ignore, true);
        p.addEventListener('keypress', ignore, true);
        p.addEventListener('keyup', ignore, true);
    }
})();
```

Comment: Only started working after deleting the "Demo" script. Safari 6.0.5.

Comment: This no longer works. Either something in stack*'s HTML/JS has changed or something in the browser has changed, but as of 1/30/2015 and Safari 8.0.3, this no longer works... I hacked on it for a while but couldn't beat it into submission before giving up.

Answer (score 3):

With Firefox 27 the already posted [Greasemonkey](https://www.greasespot.net/) scripts and bookmarklet don't work.

The bookmarklet used to work, but it doesn't anymore.

What does work is using [anti-keygrabber.user.js](https://gist.github.com/rodneyrehm/5213304) ([blog entry](https://blog.rodneyrehm.de/archives/23-Reclaim-Your-Keyboard-Shortcuts-in-Firefox.html)). In case it does not contain all keycodes you want to be excluded from being grabbed by a webpage you can easily add them.

For example to also exclude <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> you just have to add:

```js
case 73:
```

to the first switch statement:

```js
switch (e.keyCode) {
  case 87: // W - close window
  case 84: // T - open tab
  case 76: // L - focus awesome bar
  case 74: // J - open downloads panel
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here’s an updated script.

```javascript
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Stack Exchange: Kill stupid shortcuts
// @version  1
// @grant    none
// @run-at   document-start
// @match    https://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match    https://*.superuser.com/*
// @match    https://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match    https://*.mathoverflow.net/*
// @match    https://*.serverfault.com/*
// @match    https://*.askubuntu.com/*
// @match    https://stackapps.com/*
// @exclude  https://chat.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude  https://api.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude  https://data.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude  https://openid.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude  https://area51.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude  https://stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude  https://contests.stackoverflow.com/*
// @exclude  /^https?:\/\/winterbash\d{4,}\.stackexchange\.com\//
// ==/UserScript==

const ignore = ev => {
  if (!ev.target.matches('.wmd-input'))
    return;
  if (ev.ctrlKey || ev.metaKey || ev.altKey)
    ev.stopPropagation();
};

document.addEventListener('keydown', ignore, true);
document.addEventListener('keypress', ignore, true);
document.addEventListener('keyup', ignore, true);
```

Improvements relative to [Rob W’s version](/a/123256/620615):

- The event handler is attached to the document node in the capturing phase, not to the `textarea` node itself.  This ensures it will work even on editor elements not yet present on the page, allowing the script to run even before the page has finished loading (`@run-at document-start`) and avoiding a gap when the editor is usable with shortcuts not disabled yet.
- The editor element is recognised by the `wmd-input` CSS class, not by element ID.  This allows the script to work with the dynamically-inserted quick editor as well (which may be present multiple times on the page, so it doesn’t have a unique element ID), not just on the stand-alone edit page (`/posts/<...>/edit`).
- Key presses without modifier keys are passed through.  This is necessary because key presses are monitored for the purposes of bot detection and blocking unadorned key presses may [trigger CAPTCHA prompts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149365/620615).

Answer (score -3):

Most likely there is; check in your browser's settings (or at least tell us what browser you are using).

If there isn't you can easily create (or have someone create here on meta) a greasemonkey script to remove the accesskey="" attributes from HTML tags. Again, not all browsers support greasemonkey (Firefox and Chrome do, possibly others do too).

If you are asking for some kind of user setting in your account page then I'm fairly sure it's not going to happen, sorry. Very very few people "navigate" web pages using emacs keys (in fact I find this kinda funny :P) and when it comes to user interfaces less is always better: you don't want to offer 5 thousand options to your user when the average user cares about 1 or 2.

Comment: I don't navigate the page with emacs keys. Just the textboxes. I agree, less is better. Which is why I don't understand why SO takes over ctrl-b et.al.. It's horrible. Why would I want to use arrow keys or the mouse? Oh well, I guess I'll have to look into a greasemonkey script. Hmm... there are no accesskey attributes that I can see.

Comment: +1 for preferences setting to disable accesskeys in textboxes.

Comment: You say: "Very very few people "navigate" web pages using emacs keys".

First, I think you're wrong. On the Mac, every textarea and text field allows emacs keys by default--do you think that's a coincidence? 

There are a lot of emacs users out there. And they are often some of the most technical and experience developers. Do you really want to annoy them, and drive them to another site?

Also, even if there were a few, why alienate them? "Very very few people use his wheelchair ramp...let's get rid of it." :-(