# Could we have a way to turn off keyboard shortcuts in the editor box?

Tags: feature-request, keyboard-shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to disable the hotkeys?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2980/is-there-a-way-to-disable-the-hotkeys)

Google Chrome, at least on my Mac, has a rather complete set of emacs-derived keyboard bindings to control keys. SO has its own bindings on these keys. I find it hard to untrain my fingers from 30 years of emacs typing, so I find myself hitting, for example, <kbd>control-k</kbd> and getting a surprise.

I'd be grateful for a preference I could set to disable the shortcuts inside the text box.

Comment: Ctrl+K triggers inlined code...[that is in the formatting help](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: Wouldn't it be (maybe easier) possible for a user-land-script to get rid of these event-handlers?

Comment: Yes, I know that control-k is in the doc. The spiffy thing to get pictures for keyboard keys that some people like to play with, on the other hand ...

Comment: I'm ignorant on user-scripts. Care to offer a pointer?

Comment: I'm myself not very good at JavaScript, but f.e. [Greasemonkey](http://www.greasespot.net/) (and others, I think Chrome has built-in support) will allow you to run custom JavaScript code after the site as loaded. That way you can modify, resculp and enhance a website to your custom needs.

Comment: Will this work for you? [Is there a way to disable the hotkeys?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2980/is-there-a-way-to-disable-the-hotkeys/123256#123256)

Comment: look good to me.

Comment: Wow, that really befuddled TamperMonkey.

Comment: Do you think it makes sense, then, to close this question as a duplicate of the one I linked to?

Comment: Yes, go ahead. If only I could install it in chrome, but tampermonkey imploded when I tried.

Comment: Oh, well that sucks.  I hope you can get that figured out (I don't know anything about userscripts, or I would offer to help).  Also, thanks for closing @Nick - I walked away for a few hours after typing that comment =)