# Useful Dragon NaturallySpeaking voice commands for using StackExchange websites efficiently

Tags: discussion

Are there any repository of useful Dragon NaturallySpeaking voice commands for using StackExchange websites?

For example, I have defined a voice commands that attach the image `C:\Users\Francky\Downloads\Untitled.png` when editing an answer (usual filename when taking a screenshot in Windows 7):

```
Sub Main
    ' http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2980/178179
    ' opens the "Insert Image" dialog on SO,
    SendKeys "^g"

    ' Attach image in the dialog box
    Wait(1)
    SendKeys "{ENTER}"
    Wait(2)
    originalClipboard = Clipboard
    Clipboard("C:\Users\Francky\Downloads\Untitled.png")
    SendKeys "^v"
    Wait(1)
    SendKeys "{ENTER}"

    ' Click on "Add picture"
    Wait(1)
    SendKeys "{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{ENTER}"
    Clipboard(originalClipboard)
End Sub
```

I would be curious to exchange more Dragon NaturallySpeaking voice commands to use the StackExchange websites efficiently.