# Do not capture Ctrl + F/B/K keyboard events when editing in Stack Overflow Editor on Mac OS X

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, editor

On Mac OS X, these shortcuts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> belong to Mac's readline shortcut: https://jblevins.org/log/kbd

Since Stack Overflow's **editor** has used <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>/<kbd>K</kbd> as a shortcut for editing, **there isn't any need to take up the shortcut keys of the Mac system.**

I recommend the following shortcuts for Mac OS X users.

1. **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>**       Move Cursor Backwards
2. **<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>**        Bold Text
3. **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>**       Delete Text Forwards Line
4. **<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>**        Code Sample

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to disable the hotkeys?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2980/is-there-a-way-to-disable-the-hotkeys)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keyboard shortcuts are now integrated into the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237166/keyboard-shortcuts-are-now-integrated-into-the-site) - "... go to the Edit Profile & Settings page on your profile, and then select the Preferences submenu, you’ll find a new checkbox labeled Enable keyboard shortcuts ...".

Comment: @Rob No; that doesn’t affect keyboard shortcuts in the _editor_.

Comment: @user289905, retracted vote; one remains.

Comment: @pkamb Yes. Your link can solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, we could use **Karabiner** to override the default shortcuts.

```
  "description": "redline shortcuts for mac osx...",
  "manipulators": [
    {
      "type": "basic",
      "from": {
        "key_code": "p",
        "modifiers": {
          "mandatory": [
            "left_control"
          ]
        }
      },
      "to": {
          "key_code": "up_arrow"
     }
    },{
      "type": "basic",
      "from": {
        "key_code": "n",
        "modifiers": {
          "mandatory": [
            "left_control"
          ]
        }
      },
      "to": {
          "key_code": "down_arrow"
     }
    },{
```